# Concatenate one string to another with removing duplicated part

Tags: excel, vba, string, concatenation

This sounds familiar and I'm sorry if I'm repeating, but I haven't found an answer to it.
Specifically, I had this kind of situation with two strings:

**Example:**

**case 1**
Internet Site-URL
"https://mainwebsite.com:8080/specialpage/"
File-URL from href of HTML-element somewhere on that site
"/specialpage/files/videos/excel-vba/Concatenate%20one%20string%20to%20another%20with%20removing%20duplicated%20part.zip"

**case 2**
full name and date in YYYYMMDD format "John Smith 20191121"
and
date in YYYYMMDD format and work description "20191121 Resolving problems"

The end of first string is identical to the beginning of second, only by unknown length.

In both cases I needed to join the strings while removing the identical part from one of them
case 1 result "https://mainwebsite.com:8080/specialpage/files/videos/excel-vba/Concatenate%20one%20string%20to%20another%20with%20removing%20duplicated%20part.zip
case 2 result "John Smith 20191121 Resolving problems"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to IIF function, there is a solution to this sort of cases:

```
Dim String1, String2, String3 as String
Dim I as Long

' comparing parts of both strings, counting down from the length of the shorter one (IIF function)
For i = IIf(Len(String1) < Len(String2), Len(String1), Len(String2)) To 0 Step -1

' considering right side of String1 and left side of String2...
    If Right(String1, i) = Left(String2, i) Then

        ' for example, overlapping was in "/specialpage/"; we took String1 without this part and joined it with String2
        String3 = Left(String1, Len(String1) - i) & String2
        Exit For

    End If

' the length of both strings' parts we compare is gradually shortened...
Next i
```